# How is wicket handling html injection

Tags: java, wicket

when I create html page with this code:

```
 '<br/>' is not a valid email address.
```

I see instead of `<br />` is new line what is OK

Then I have wicket input text field where I have EmailValidator. When I put there `<br />` I can see same line but `<br />` inst replace by new line. How it is wicket doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want any html code be seen in the browser, you need to escape it. If you use html as value in wicket components, you need to call `Component.setEscapeModelStrings(true);`

Comment: But when you do, you expose yourself to all kinds of injection and cross-site scripting attacks, so be VERY careful when you use it.

Comment: @biziclop good point, if the data is coming from user input, than be very very vareful